# layout_margin is ignored when add the view in the view group

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use HorizontalScrollView with a child LinearLayout view.
I want an item fill the screen with margins, and the next item be able to be seen after scrolling. To make you understand, I will tell you everything I tried with codes.

First, I fixed the width, height, and margins of the items.

```
<com.example.kanbanboard.TaskListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/container">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</com.example.kanbanboard.TaskListView>
```

The layout of this parent is

```
<com.example.kanbanboard.MyHorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="1dp" // It seems that whether 1dp or fill_parent does not matter
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000">
    </LinearLayout>

</com.example.kanbanboard.MyHorizontalScrollView>
```

and Here is the code which add View in the Linear Layout

```
public void init(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
    //CategoryView is almost same with TaskListView
    CategoryView categoryList = (CategoryView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, parent, false);
    TaskListView taskList = (TaskListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list_layout,
                                                            parent, false);
    categoryList.init(taskList);
    taskList.init();

    View[] children = new View[]{categoryList, taskList};
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new MainLayoutListener(parent, children);
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}

class MainLayoutListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{

    ViewGroup parent;
    View[] children;

    public MainLayoutListener(ViewGroup parent, View[] children){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout(){
        ScrollView me = ScrollView.this;
        me.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        parent.addView(children[0]);
        parent.addView(children[1]);
    }
}
```

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu4t5.png

The margin was not ignored, but the item does not fit to the screen.
So I tried to use fill_parent in layout_width and layout_height, but the result was

http://imgur.com/y2yNWmz&zIe1gTN#0

I also tried to set the width, height, and margin  with LayoutParams.

```
        ScrollView me = ScrollView.this;
        me.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        int w = me.getMeasuredWidth() - 50 // for margin;
        int h = me.getMeasuredHeight() - 50;

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(w, h);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        parent.addView(children[0], params);
        parent.addView(children[1], params);
```

With the above code, I could fit the item to the screen, but the margin was ignored.

I hope you understand my problem. How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use View Pager Instead of Making it yourself

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

use this for reference